# poetry returns 'dyld: Library not loaded ... image not found' following brew install while inside virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, pyenv, python-poetry, virtual-environment

I ran `brew install postgresql` while inside a poetry environment. Since then, I can't interact with poetry.

```
λ ~/ poetry
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/<my username>/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
[1]    5634 abort      poetry
```

I get the same output when I try `poetry <any other command>`. I tried removing my virtual environments from `λ ~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/` expecting to be able to reinstall them from the `.toml` files in my projects, but can't run `poetry install` because I receive the same error.

I am running MacOS 10.15.7, Homebrew 3.3.12, poetry 1.1.12, & pyenv 2.2.4.

```
ECHO $PATH
/Users/<my username>/.poetry/bin:~/.local/bin:/Users/<my username>/Library/Python/3.9/bin:/shims:/Users/<my username>/.datacoral/cli/bin:/Users/<my username>/.nvm/versions/node/v12.13.0/bin:/Users/<my username>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/<my username>/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/<my username>/.local/bin:/Users/<my username>/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 55):

I faced this issue because when I executed brew install, brew updated the patch version of Python from `3.9.13_1` to `3.9.14`.

This can be easily resolved by running the following to uninstall and then install poetry.

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

Comment: does not work in my case

Comment: @Allan-J Please add some context as to why it didn't work for you.

Comment: This also did not work for me. The error: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Python and then zsh: no such file or directory: /use/lib/Python

Answer (score 17):

This is because brew might have installed using a different python version.

To fix this, we need to uninstall poetry, if you are using pyenv, change to required python version and then re-install poetry. Now poetry should be installed with the required python version.

```bash
# Uninstall poetry
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall

# change to required python
pyenv local 3.10.8

# activate python
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"

# check python version
python --version

# Install latest poetry
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

Comment: This solved my problem, now the poetry referring the python version set by pyenv instead of system default. thanks

Comment: @sairam What a genius !! saved my day buddy, This has to be an accepted answer

Comment: This answer works for me. I also uninstalled the brew version.

Answer (score 16):

I'm resolving this in case someone runs into the same issue.

Uninstalling and reinstalling poetry fixed the problem. I wasn't able to do this with the `--uninstall` option and instead had to do it manually. I first ran `rm -rf pypoetry` inside  `~/Library/Application Support/`. Then I re-ran the install line from poetry's site: `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`.

The cause of the issue was using `poetry shell` instead of just `poetry run jupyterlab` –– this opened me up to absent-mindedly screwing up the poetry install by running brew installs while in the shell. Lesson learned!

Comment: You magnificent beauty.

Comment: @eve-hunt Are you sure its caused by running brew install in poetry shell? My feeling is there are chances normal brew installs updates python in brew, say like a patch version and poetry would be pointing to old version's location.

Comment: Just to add to this, for me it was enough to just update poetry with `poetry self update`

Comment: totally solved it. I think i ran brew update/upgrade (whichever does the installed apps updates) inside a poetry shell. Lesson learned!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 15):

I tried all the above solutions, even searched for possible `poetry` entries in different places of the system, all deleted and uninstalled. Nothing worked, and as I have Python (3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11) installed on macOS with homebrew, the only solution was to install `poetry` via homebrew too.

```
brew install poetry
```

Comment: I have Python 3.11 installed with home brew and this was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: I tried all the other answers, but this one worked immediately. Thank you! This needs to be in the poetry docs. I would have done this first.

Comment: Worked like charm.

Answer (score 11):

At the time of writing, there is an open issue in the poetry repo for installations failing on macos: https://github.com/python-poetry/install.python-poetry.org/issues/24

There is a workaround posted in [this comment](https://github.com/python-poetry/install.python-poetry.org/issues/24#issuecomment-1692427804):

```bash
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | sed 's/symlinks=False/symlinks=True/' | python3 -
```